# Firebase Saving Object as Key to Database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
router.post('/postChef', function(req, res, next) {
    var userid = req.body.userID;
    var mealid = req.body.mealID;
    db.ref("chefs/" + userid).child("Meals").set({
        mealid : true
    });
    res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

In the code above, I'm not sure why mealid gets changed into a "mealid" in the firebase database. What I want is the string value of mealid given by the function. How can I do this? In the defined path, Meals is a child containing a JSON list of all the mealIDs set to true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use the term "mealid" on the left-hand side of a property assigned, it is interpreted as a string and not as a variable.

To use *the value of* `mealid` as the name of the property, switch to "square bracket" notation:

```
router.post('/postChef', function(req, res, next) {
    var userid = req.body.userID;
    var mealid = req.body.mealID;
    var obj = {};
    obj[mealid] = true;
    db.ref("chefs/" + userid).child("Meals").set(obj);
    res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```